# Failed to compile PuTTY for Windows: fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winresrc.h'

Tags: c, windows, makefile, compiler-errors, putty

I am trying to compile [PuTTY for Windows](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/putty-src.zip) on my Windows 10 machine. After I download the [source code](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/putty-src.zip), I followed the steps from the README file:

```
For building on Windows:

 - windows/Makefile.vc is for command-line builds on MS Visual C++
   systems. Change into the `windows' subdirectory and type `nmake
   -f Makefile.vc' to build all the PuTTY binaries.
```

I needed to add the following path to the `PATH` environment variable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64
```

Because the `Makefile.vc` is calling `rc` without absolute path.
I run the make file and received the following error:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Putty For Windows\windows>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.vc

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24234.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        rc /Fopageant.res  -r -I..\./ -I..\charset/ -I..\windows/ -I..\unix/ -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -DWINVER=0x0400 ..\windows\pageant.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 10.0.10011.16384
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

..\windows\rcstuff.h(15) : fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winresrc.h'.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64\rc.EXE"' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

It writes that it can't open the include file `winresrc.h`.
This file doesn't exist in the PuTTY source folder, so I tried to copy the file from my Windows 10 SDK path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\winresrc.h
```

But I received the same error even after I copied the include file to the folder of `Putty For Windows\windows`.

Comment: `nmake -f makefile.vc` That must be run at a cmd prompt configured for your installation of VC++ (or the VC++ build tools), and that means not just the PATH but also INCLUDE, LIB and the whole environment. Open a [developer command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160#open-a-developer-command-prompt) and run the `nmake` command at that prompt.

Comment: @dxiv thanks, it works. Please publish it as an answer and I will mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nmake -f makefile.vc` must be run at a cmd prompt configured for an installation of VC++ (or the VC++ build tools), and that means not just the PATH but also INCLUDE, LIB etc. It will work if run at a [VS developer command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160#open-a-developer-command-prompt), which sets the whole environment correctly.

As an alternative, the [PuTTY for Windows package](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/) comes with Visual C++ `.sln` and `.vcxproj` project files for building from the IDE. The `windows\vs2012\putty.sln` solution imports fine into the latest VS 2019, and builds (albeit with many warnings) after fixing the header references in `putty-src\windows\version.rc2`.

```
    #include "..\\version.h"  // instead of "version.h"
    #include "..\\licence.h"  // instead of "license.h"
```